# How do i execute a angular function in a controller, from a @Html.ActionLink()?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my view i have the following `actionlink`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {click="TestFunction()"})
```

instead of calling a js function i need to call a function in the Angular controller's $scope. Assume the above `TestFunction()` is in the `$scope` then i need to use the `ng-click` instead of `click`. But .net wont let me use `ng-click` as anonymous property so rewriting

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {ng-click="TestFunction()"})
```

is not possible, so how do i add the function `TestFunction()` in angular controller to the `actionlink`

Comment: If you want to add a an attribute `ng-click` then it needs to be `new {ng_click = "TestFunction()" }` (underscore character, not hyphen) - the razor engine will convert it to a hyphen

Comment: @StephenMuecke is this the way to attach a click to an action link?

Comment: For non-angular (your first code snippet), then no. Use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). For angular, I have no idea (I don't use it)

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ActionLink` is Server side MVC implementation for generating Link on your HTML page.

onclick is javascript implementaiton to generate click event and call function available in DOM as mentioned in html.

ng-click is angular dir. implementation to generate click event and call function under $scope as mentioned in html.

```
    for razor-c# , ng-click is an invalid syntax you should use ng_click
  to create angular click event for ActionLink Only.
```

If you are building a link that doesn't involve server stuff AND you are building app that uses AngularJS I would suggest to render html `a` tag.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="...">
```

If you are anyway needs server implementation , create partial view (with actionlinks you want to use) that returns html and use angular directive to place in your DOM.

Hope this helps...